# Microsoft Reporting WebForms Report Viewer - Exporting to Excel

Tags: asp.net, .net, webforms, reportviewer

I have a report viewer that I am using to export to PDF and Excel. Sometimes some of the data in the tables is longer than a singular line.

When exported to PDF the fields that need more height are automatically given it. Yet when I export to excel it remains in the original height and doesn't grow to display all the data.

I want the cell heights to automatically grow to display all the data on screen. I have set `CanGrow` to `true` but this has no effect (apart from working when exporting to PDF).

Has anyone had this problem before and can share a resolution?

Thanks

Comment: I guess the Report Viewer is a bit of a dinosaur these days!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after not receiving any answers I delved in to this one myself.

It appears that text doesn't wrap in excel when the cell is a number of merged cells together.

So in the report viewer if all text areas and items aren't lined up with one another or if one is twice as long as two others then they will be placed in merged cells to make up for the crossover.

It means that the chances are these isn't a solution to the problem, unless all your text areas are identical in width or you can alter the layout so that those that require wrapping to new lines will only take up a single cell.

I done this by putting everything in a table, and knowing that if I merged any cells then text wrapping would not be possible.

I hope this will help someone out there!